# stylesheet that filters the nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml. I need to remove few elements based on another xml node.

Input xml:

```
<json:object xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
    <json:object name="userProfile">
        <json:string name="dob">1940-03-21</json:string>
        <json:string name="gender">Male</json:string>
        <json:string name="firstName">John</json:string>
        <json:string name="lastName">Doe</json:string>
        <json:string name="Prefix">Mr</json:string>
        <json:string name="middleName">Jane</json:string>
        <json:string name="email">johndoe@test.com</json:string>
        <json:string name="country">USA</json:string>
        <json:array name="addresses">
            <json:object>
                <json:string name="type">1</json:string>
                <json:string name="line1">ABCD St</json:string>
                <json:string name="line2">Unit # 234</json:string>
                <json:string name="city">Tampa</json:string>
                <json:string name="state">FL</json:string>
                <json:string name="country">USA</json:string>
                <json:string name="zipCode">33637</json:string>
            </json:object>
        </json:array>
        <json:array name="phones">
            <json:object>
                <json:string name="number">1234567890</json:string>
                <json:string name="type">Home</json:string>
            </json:object>
            <json:object>
                <json:string name="number">1231231230</json:string>
                <json:string name="type">Cell</json:string>
            </json:object>
            <json:object>
                <json:string name="number">8881212121</json:string>
                <json:string name="type">Business</json:string>
            </json:object>
        </json:array>
    </json:object>
</json:object>
```

Filter xml:

```
<Filter>
<Item>gender</Item>
<Item>email</Item>
<Item>addresses</Item>
</Filter>
```

Using this I need to write stylesheets.

1. Stylesheet that filters  those three filters (remove those three
   elements) and populate the rest of the elements as is.
2. Stylesheet that populates only those three elements that are in filter and
   remove the rest of the elements.

The list in the filter can be dynamical. I can't hardcode in my xsl.. How to achieve this in xslt

Comment: If you keep only the listed elements and remove all the rest, you will very likely end up with an ill-formed XML (i.e. not  XML) document.

Comment: I agree. For the second use case, The top object userProfile needs to be there, which I forgot to mention, which makes it a valid xml. And some times  the object name might be different than userProfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the elements whose name is listed in the `filter.xml` document, do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="filter" select="'filter.xml'"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@name = document($filter)/Filter/Item]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This assumes all listed elements are leaf nodes (i.e. have no children). Otherwise you'd have to do:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@name = document($filter)/Filter/Item]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to remove the listed elements, but keep their descendants (*if* that's the desired result).